# Regular expression for letters, dash, underscore, numbers, and space

Tags: python, regex

This is my attempt

```
def matcher(ex):
    if re.match(r'^[\w|\d][A-Za-z0-9_-]+$', ex):
        print 'yes'
```

My goal is to match only submission that satisfy all the followings

1. begins with only a letter or a numeric digit, and
2. only letter, space, dash, underscore and numeric digit are allowed
3. all ending spaces are stripped

In my regex, `matcher('__')` is considered valid. How can I modify to achieve what I want really want? I believe `\w` also includes underscore. But `matcher('_')` is not matched...

Comment: `\w` is `[0-9A-Za-z_]`, and your regex asserts at least 2 characters.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
def matcher(ex):
    ex = ex.rstrip()
    if re.match(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9][ A-Za-z0-9_-]*$', ex):
        print 'yes'
```

Problems in your original regex:

1. `|` doesn't mean alternation in a character class, it means a pipe character literally.
2. You used `+` for your following characters, meaning one or more, so a one-character string like `'_'` wouldn't match.
3. You used `\w` in your first character, which accepted underscores.

Comment: ... need a space in your second clause

Comment: Also to strip ending spaces, just use `mystring.rstrip()` instead of regex.

Comment: @Ned Batchelder This is very nice. But why `|` doesn't mean `or` in this context? Thanks.

Comment: @user1012451: regex syntax says character classes work that way.  The only special character inside `[]` is a leading `^`, meaning "not these characters," and `-` in the middle, meaning a range of characters.

Comment: @NedBatchelder and everyone else, thank you! I've learned something new :)